# Evaluate the following integral $\int_{0}^{10}\sqrt{-175e^{-t/4}+400}dt$

Tags: calculus, integration

I am trying to evalute the following integral:
$$\int_{0}^{10}\sqrt{-175e^{-t/4}+400}dt$$
Any suggestions how to start?
Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make the substitution

$$u=400-175 e^{-t/4} \implies t = -4 \log{\frac{400-u}{175}} \implies dt = \frac{4}{400-u} du$$

The integral is then equal to

$$4 \int_{225}^{400-175 e^{-5/2}} \frac{du}{400-u} \sqrt{u}$$

Then make the substitution $u=v^2$ to get a more familiar form:

$$8 \int_{15}^{\sqrt{400-175 e^{-5/2}}} dv \frac{v^2}{400-v^2} = 8  \int_{15}^{\sqrt{400-175 e^{-5/2}}} dv  \left (\frac{400}{400-v^2} - 1 \right )$$

Use the fact that

$$\int \frac{dy}{a^2-y^2} = \frac12 \log{\frac{a+y}{a-y}}$$

and the rest is arithmetic.

Comment: The Maple code $$with(Student[Calculus1]):
IntTutor(sqrt(-175*exp(-(1/4)*t)+400), t = 0 .. 10);
 $$ does it better, step by step, with explanations, and outputing the answer $$-40\sqrt{-7e^{-5/2}+16}+40 \sqrt{9}-80\ln(-\sqrt{-7e^{-5/2}+16}+4)+80\ln(4-\sqrt{9})+80\ln(\sqrt{-7e^{-5/2}+16}+4)-80\ln(\sqrt{9}+4).$$

Comment: @user64494: I don't doubt Maple can do that - Wolfram Alpha can, too.  But, better?   That's an entirely subjective assessment of something you didn't bother to post in its entirety.  And people here may not want Maple output - if they did, then they'd go ask Maple.